# Jasper report - Collapsible Input section

Tags: jasperserver

Is there a way to make the input section (filters) collapsible while viewing the report in jasper? This is to get a wider view of the entire report. The input section takes away some space. So, once I select my filters, I would want a mechanism to collapse it. Is there a way for this?

Thanks
Rathi

Answer (score 0):

If you right-click the report in the repository browser and choose Edit, you can customize how the input controls layout in the report viewer, for example you could choose Pop-up window.

See here for a description of all the layouts: https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jasperreports-server-ultimate-guide/v640/customizing-report-rendering-page

Comment: Thank you Kamal, I have used In - page option and this is the option my clients are happy with. However, I want the entire filter section to be collapsible, so that, when I need to change  the filter conditions I can change and apply and also , hide it.

Comment: That's exactly what the Pop-up layout does, have you tried it? Can you vote up the answer if you found it useful?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way. You can use **"Input Controls"** icon available in the Report Viewer Tool Bar to show/ hide the filters for a report. See image here:
[Show-Hide Input controls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3n9U.png)

Alternatively, if you got Commercial edition of Jasper Reports Server, you can create your own custom report viewer page to add auto hide feature for input controls (filters) and can embed reports inside it using **Visualize.js**.

Comment: This only comes for a pop up window. Does not appear for a In Page menu